# Code Tidying up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

This has been answered in full here: 
[link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/24499/code-tidying-up) 
what is this best way to tidy up javascript code I have written this but it seems very long winded any suggestions to shorten it?

```
jQuery("document").ready(function(jQuery){

if ( jQuery(window).width() < 960) {
        jQuery(".main").animate({"top":"22%"});
        jQuery('#tblcontents').toggle(function(){
        jQuery(".main").fadeOut(1000);
         }, function(){ 
        jQuery(".main").fadeIn(1000);
        jQuery(".main").animate({"top":"22%"});

    });

}
else {
}

    jQuery('.menu-button').click(function(){
    jQuery("#sb-container div").css("transform", "rotate(0deg)"  );
    jQuery("#sb-container div").css("-webkit-transform", "rotate(0deg)"  );
    jQuery("#sb-container div").css("-ms-transform", "rotate(0deg)"  );
    jQuery("#sb-container div").css("-moz-transform", "rotate(0deg)"  );
    jQuery("#sb-container div").css("-o-transform", "rotate(0deg)"  );
    jQuery(".main").animate({"right":"1%"}, "slow");
});

jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('.toggle_div').toggle(function(){
    jQuery(".main").animate({"right":"50%"}, "slow");
 }, function(){ 
    jQuery(".main").animate({"right":"1%"}, "slow");
    });
});

jQuery(".pulse").effect("pulsate", { times:100 }, 2000).click(function(){
    jQuery(".pulse").effect().stop(true, true);
    jQuery(".pulse").animate({"opacity":"1"}, "fast");
});
    jQuery('.thumb').click(function(){
    jQuery("#sb-container div").css("transform", "rotate(0deg)"  );
    jQuery("#sb-container div").css("-webkit-transform", "rotate(0deg)"  );
    jQuery("#sb-container div").css("-ms-transform", "rotate(0deg)"  );
    jQuery("#sb-container div").css("-moz-transform", "rotate(0deg)"  );
    jQuery("#sb-container div").css("-o-transform", "rotate(0deg)"  );
    jQuery("#sb-container").animate({"left":"0px"}, "slow");
    jQuery(".main").animate({"right":"1%"}, "slow");
    });

jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
    if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 20) {
    jQuery("#sb-container div").css("transform", "rotate(0deg)"  );
    jQuery("#sb-container div").css("-webkit-transform", "rotate(0deg)"  );
    jQuery("#sb-container div").css("-ms-transform", "rotate(0deg)"  );
    jQuery("#sb-container div").css("-moz-transform", "rotate(0deg)"  );
    jQuery("#sb-container div").css("-o-transform", "rotate(0deg)"  );
    jQuery(".main").animate({"right":"1%"}, "slow");

    } else{
            jQuery( "#sb-container" ).draggable()
    }
});

});

     jQuery(function() {
jQuery( "#sb-container" ).draggable()
});
```

How do I go about reducing the amount of code shown here? 
what are the best practices and what am i missing? 
also do i need the else statements querying the window width since they don't have any functions in them for the most part. 
Chris

Comment: You should try codereview.stackexchange.com, it would be better suited to this question. As a first note, though, you can use $ instead of jQuery. That'll save a fair amount.

Comment: Thank you I will pop over there now :D should i remove the question from here to stop double posting?

Comment: Did you try using Minifying tools too shorten the length by removing white spaces and renaming variable names ? You can do away with the jQuery keyword and use $ instead without losing any functionality.

Comment: more than minifing it I mean actually using some dom traversal and chaining the functions and such...
I'm running it on Wordpress which runs jQuery in nonconflict mode.

Comment: create one css properties object instead of making multiple `css()` calls and cache selectors you use more than once, or expect to search same selector in DOm numerous times

Comment: @vimes1984 chaining would help, as would combining your css queries and using $ instead of jquery.  Lots of unnecessary repetition right now.  Good that you want to get better though.

Comment: @ben336 thank I used var `j$ = jQuery.noConflict();` to return jQuery from non conflict, is there any issues with that?

Comment: had a very complete answer [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/24499/code-tidying-up/24503?noredirect=1#comment37859_24503)

Answer (score 2):

You can clean up some components of your code by doing bulk setting of styles like this:

```
// it looks like you reuse this same set of styles in a few places
// define them once as a variable and assign as needed
var defaultStyles = 
{
    "transform": "rotate(0deg)",
    "-webkit-transform": "rotate(0deg)",
    "-ms-transform": "rotate(0deg)",
    "-moz-transform": "rotate(0deg)",
    "-o-transform": "rotate(0deg)"
};
```

---

```
jQuery('.menu-button').click(function() {
    jQuery("#sb-container div").css(defaultStyles);
    jQuery(".main").animate({"right":"1%"}, "slow");
});
```

---

```
jQuery('.thumb').click(function(){
    jQuery("#sb-container div").css(defaultStyles);
    jQuery("#sb-container").animate({"left":"0px"}, "slow");
    jQuery(".main").animate({"right":"1%"}, "slow");
});
```

---

```
if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 20) {
    jQuery("#sb-container div").css(defaultStyles);
    jQuery(".main").animate({"right":"1%"}, "slow");
}
```